# How can I find a node containing a sub-string?

Tags: xml, xpath, vbscript, asp-classic

I am able to find nodes in an XML file using the following statement:

```vb
Set user = objXMLDoc.selectSingleNode("//user[@id = '" & id & "']")
```

But the XML files I'm reading are being generated automatically and sometimes contain spaces after the ID. The `id` attribute of the `user` node might look like either of the following:

```xml
<user id="E12345" name="Dan Smith">
<user id="E12345 " name="Dan Smith">
```

Right now this appears to be the only variation in the data. I have no control over the generation of the files and cannot force a TRIM at that end. So I have to handle in my code.

What's the simplest way to work around this? Is there some kind of `InStr` method I could use?

Currently I'm coding around it like this, but this feels clumsy and only handles exceptions when there is one extra space:

```vb
Set user = objXMLDoc.selectSingleNode("//user[@id = '" & id & "']")
If user Is Nothing Then 
    Set user = objXMLDoc.selectSingleNode("//user[@id = '" & id & " ']")
End If
```

Comment: Where are you looking for information about XPath before you ask on StackOverflow? I'm really surprised you should have difficulty finding this information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`contains()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256195(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Set user = objXMLDoc.selectSingleNode("//user[contains(@id,'" & id & "')]")
```

or if spaces appear only at the end of string you can use [`starts-with()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256174(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Set user = objXMLDoc.selectSingleNode("//user[starts-with(@id,'" & id & "')]")
```

Comment: Awesome. Thank you so much. I'm brand new to Xpath and XML. If you don't mind my asking, is there is a good reference or tutorial you would recommend so I could learn the available methods, properties, etc.?

Comment: @JohnCherry you can look at [reference on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256115(v=vs.110).aspx) for starters

Comment: Thank you, I'll have a look. I slotted your code into my script but now I don't get any results. Is there a syntax error in there somewhere? Well, now that I know about the contains method I can try to figure it out myself.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the second option, I modified the contains example to use the same syntax and now both work perfectly! Updated to:

Set user = objXMLDoc.selectSingleNode("//user[contains(@id,'" & id & "')]")

Answer (score 3):

Remove leading/trailing whitespace with the [`normalize-space()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms256063.aspx) function:

```vb
xpath = "//user[normalize-space(@id) = '" & id & "']"
Set user = objXMLDoc.selectSingleNode(xpath)
```

Note that you'll need to use version 6 of the XML library for this to work:

```vb
Set objXMLDoc = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0")
```

Earlier version don't provide this method, so you'll get an "unknown method" error:

> Unknown method.
>
> //user[-->normalize-space(@<--id)='E12345'] (0x80004005)